Difference between -v, -z and -n while comparing variables in a shell script
There are the following ways to check if a variable is available or not in a linux/unix shell script
[ ! -z "${MYVARIABLE}" ] 

OR
[ -n "${MYVARIABLE}" ]

OR
[[ ! -v MYVARIABLE ]]

What is the difference between these three? When should one be preferred over the other? Also if we try to combine them then an error is given. For example if we give the following code it works fine
if [ ! -z "${PROFILEHOME}" ] && [ -n "${PROFILEHOME}" ];
then
    echo "Profile home variable that is being used is $PROFILEHOME"
else
    echo "Profile home is not set"
fi

However if we try to execute the following
if [[ ! -v MYVARIABLE ]] && [ ! -z "${PROFILEHOME}" ] && [ -n "${PROFILEHOME}" ];
then
    echo "Profile home variable that is being used is $PROFILEHOME"
else
    echo "Profile home is not set"
fi

then the shell script returns an error message, "[: -v: unexpected operator"
The difference between -z and -n operators that is given over here simply states that -z is to check when string is null while -n is to check if it is not null

Consider looking at the bash manual rather than at a third party site. That site is using terms like “null” in a way that could lead to confusion. The -z and -n tests are exact opposites of each other, so there is never any point in using both like you show in the question.

Are you sure you’re running your script with bash?

Your use of "available" conflates two different concepts: a variable can be entirely undefined (in which case its expansion produces an empty string), or it can be defined (which includes being assigned the empty string).

The tldp site mentioned in the question is notoriously riddled with misinformation, never refer to it for anything.

@Kusalananda I checked I am using /bin/sh, which in my system is a syslink to dash. So to answer your question no I am not using bash but I am using dash.

@chepner so if I want to check whether a variable is entirely undefined how can that be done? The -z and -n option just checks whether the variable has been assigned a value.

-v always tests for the existence of a parameter, whether its value is empty or not.
$ unset x
$ [[ -v x ]] && echo set
$ x=
$ [[ -v x ]] && echo set
set
$ x=1
$ [[ -v x ]] && echo set
set

-z only tests if a string is empty or not. It doesn't know or care about parameters; $x just provides the string to test, and unset parameters always expand to the empty string, just like empty parameters.
$ unset x
$ [[ -z "$x" ]] && echo empty
empty
$ x=
$ [[ -z "$x" ]] && echo empty
empty
$ x=1
$ [[ -z "$x" ]] && echo empty
$

-n is the opposite of -z, so [[ ! -n "$x" ]] and [[ -z "$x" ]] are equivalent for the same parameter x, whether it is set or not.
Because unset parameters expand to the empty string, [[ -v x ]] succeeding doesn't tell you if [[ -z "$x" ]] will succeed or not, and [[ -z "$x" ]] succeeding doesn't tell you if [[ -v x ]] will succeed or not.
